# How to check if a window button is pressed C++

Tags: c++, winapi, api

How can I test if a button is being pressed ?
I am using EnumChildWindows() to enumerate the child windows of a given window, and one of the child window is a button, I want to test if that specific button is being pressed.
My code until know is:

```
BOOL CALLBACK MyEnumProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    char buffer[256];
    GetWindowText(hwnd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    cout << buffer << endl;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    HWND hwnd = FindWindow(0, "Window to find");
    EnumChildWindows(hwnd, MyEnumProc, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to do something when the user clicks the button, or do you just want to check the pressed state? Checking for BST_PUSHED is not a very common practice. If the user clicks quickly, BST_PUSHED will be set only for a very brief period of time. Typically applications handle button presses by listen for a WM_COMMAND message in their window proc instead. More information on your scenario might help: is this a window in your process, or another process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send the [BM_GETSTATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775988%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) message to the button control, if it is pressed the result will be 
BST_PUSHED.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject a DLL into the process space, hook the window message loop (like you used to hand code a subclassed window in native Win32 API C code, Window Proc) (google-able) and listen to the actual messages.

All of this is ancient stuff for me, and I'm afraid that recent Windows versions (hopefully) made this a little bit more difficult to do.

That said, if you can get the application trusted with the right level of permissions, you should still be able to do this